# VS Code + PHP Intelephense + Remote-SSH + Symfony 3 : undefined method error

Tags: visual-studio-code, symfony-3.4, vscode-remote, intelephense

I'm discovering VS Code, I am a complete newbie with this code editor, before I used Atom but I want to use VS Code which looks very cool!

I have a Symfony 3 project on a Linux server and I want to directly modify its files because it's a dev environment. I don't want to have a local copy.

So, I installed VS Code on my PC and I downloaded Remote-SSH and PHP Intelephense extensions. After several problem, I managed to make it work but I have a lot of issues inside my Controllers because PHP Intelephense doesn't recognize a lot of methods whereas it should do.

I turned off the built-in PHP Language Features of VS Code.

For example, here are some undefined methods :

It doesn't recognize `$repository->createQueryBuilder()` or `$em->createQuery()` or custom functions inside `Repository` class of entities. It doesn't recognize some functions defined inside the Controller itself whereas they are correctly defined.
It doesn't recognize the Symfony basic repository methods like `$repo->findOneByProperty()`, etc.

So my files are full of errors while everything is normal! ^^

Can someone help me ? If Remote-SSH isn't the best extension, maybe you can advise me another one ? Same thing for Intelephense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to have the project in local and use `SFTP` extension (by liximomo) to upload files on the server after saving them. `PHP Intelephense` is working well with that configuration. `Symfony for VScode` extension (by TheNouillet) can be useful too.

**settings.json**

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "twig": "html"
},
"symfony-vscode.phpExecutablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php5.6.16\\php.exe",
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true,
    "**/vendor/**": true
},
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
},
"php.suggest.basic": false,
"intelephense.files.exclude": [
    "**/.git/**",
    "**/.svn/**",
    "**/.hg/**",
    "**/CVS/**",
    "**/.DS_Store/**",
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/bower_components/**",
    "**/vendor/**/{Test,test,Tests,tests}/**/*Test.php"
],
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods": false
```